# convexity of a Hessian matrix.

Tags: calculus, matrices, convex-analysis

Suppose I have $f(x_{1},x_{2}) = x_{1}^2 + x_{2}^2, S = \mathbb{R}^2$.

How do I determine whether the function is concave or convex based off of the Hessian of what is above?

I know the Hessian is a square matrix, and in this case, we have a 2 by 2 matrix with the top left and bottom right entry as 2, while the other two places are zero. I am just unsure how to look at it and determine whether it is concave or convex.

Comment: use to give yourself an idea: [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x_1%5E2%2Bx_2%5E2%2C ]

Answer (score 1):

To have a convex function, you need that the hessian is [positive semidefinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) often this is a pain to check, but the identity is positive semidefinite, and your matrix is twice the identity. Thus the function is convex.

It should be noted again, though, that the function is convex, not the Hessian.